# rails: removing underscore from controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-url, prettify

when I generate a two word named controller, like `FooBar` rails creates a controller and path like `foo_bar` this is not pretty. I would like to have the paths at least be `FooBar`.

Possible? Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on how your route is defined in routes.rs. For example:

```
# if you have named routes
map.foobar '/foobar/:action', :controller => 'foobar'

# if you have resources, this will generate
map.resources :foo_bar, :as => 'foobar'
```

This is for Rails 2.3.*, it's slightly different in Rails 3.